# Don't understand this ERROR : Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’

Tags: haskell

My Error is shown below, I am trying to create a function that displays a Sudoku like grid using the showGrid Function and intersperse, showRow and group.

[image]

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling Tutorial9        ( Tutorial9.hs, interpreted )

Tutorial9.hs:39:28: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected type: [Char]
        Actual type: [[Char]]
    • In the second argument of ‘splitOn’, namely
        ‘(intersperse
            "-------------" (groupBy 39 (unwords [showRow xs | xs <- x])))’
      In the expression:
        splitOn
          "9|"
          (intersperse
             "-------------" (groupBy 39 (unwords [showRow xs | xs <- x])))
      In an equation for ‘showGrid’:
          showGrid x
            = splitOn
                "9|"
                (intersperse
                   "-------------" (groupBy 39 (unwords [showRow xs | xs <- x])))
   |
39 | showGrid x = splitOn "9|" (intersperse "-------------" (groupBy 39 (unwords [ showRow xs | xs <- x ])))
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I don't know why I get this error and how to resolve it. The relevant code is shown below.

Any help would be appreciated

```
    
    groupBy :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    ...
    
    showRow :: String -> String
    ...

    showGrid :: Matrix Digit -> [String]
    showGrid x = splitOn "9|" (intersperse "-------------" (groupBy 39 (concat [ showRow xs | xs <- x ])))
```

Comment: You might want to clarify function `intersperse`. It is using `x` as both an argument and a dummy variable inside the list comprehension. This is a bit confusing. Besides, the 2 arguments of the `splitOn` library function have the same type. So you probably want to pass the result of `intersperse` thru `concat` before passing it over to `splitOn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the faulty code slightly, in order to have everything in sight at the same time, without having to fight with the horizontal ruler:

```
intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]
intersperse x y = x : [ x | ys <- y, x <- [ys, x]]

showGrid :: Matrix Digit -> [String]
showGrid xss =
    let  rectangles = groupBy 39 (concat [ showRow xs | xs <- xss ])
    in   splitOn  "9|"  (intersperse  "-------------"  rectangles)
```

This rewrite does not alter the error message.

The `splitOn` library function has this type signature: `splitOn :: Eq t => [t] -> [t] -> [[t]]`
Now, how do we interpret type `t` ? Well, the first argument of `splitOn` is "9|", and it has to be of type `[t]`, hence type `t` must be `Char`. A `String` is just a list of `Char`s.

As the two arguments of `splitOn` have the same type, it follows that for this code to typecheck, function `intersperse` should also return a String.

But from the type signature of `intersperse :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, its return type is a *list* of its first argument, which happens to be a String, namely "-------------". So, function `intersperse` returns a list of `String`s instead of a single string. Hence the type mismatch flagged by the compiler.

You can fix this by running the result of `intersperse` thru the `concat` library function. The `concat` function makes a single sum string out of a list of strings. That gives us this code:

```
showGrid :: Matrix Digit -> [String]
showGrid xss =
    let  rectangles = (groupBy 39 (concat [ showRow xs | xs <- xss ]))
    in   splitOn  "9|"  (concat (intersperse "-------------" rectangles))
```

which does compile without errors.

However, there is a slight problem caused by the fact that the "-------------" separator strings do not end with "9|".

The problem can be then fixed by noting that we want all output lines to be exactly 13 characters long. Hence the following code, with the `printAsLines` small debugging utility added:

```
showGrid :: Matrix Digit -> [String]
showGrid xss =
    let  rectangles = (groupBy 39 (concat [ showRow xs | xs <- xss ]))
    in   groupBy  13  (concat (intersperse "-------------" rectangles))

printAsLines :: Show α => [α] -> IO ()
printAsLines xs = mapM_  (putStrLn . show)  xs
```

**Testing under the `ghci` interpreter:**

```
 λ> 
 λ> :load q64988685.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( q64988685.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> matrix = replicate 9 "123456789"
 λ> yss = showGrid matrix
 λ> 
 λ> yss
["-------------","|123|456|789|","|123|456|789|","|123|456|789|","-------------","|123|456|789|","|123|456|789|","|123|456|789|","-------------","|123|456|789|","|123|456|789|","|123|456|789|","-------------"]
 λ> 
 λ> printAsLines yss
"-------------"
"|123|456|789|"
"|123|456|789|"
"|123|456|789|"
"-------------"
"|123|456|789|"
"|123|456|789|"
"|123|456|789|"
"-------------"
"|123|456|789|"
"|123|456|789|"
"|123|456|789|"
"-------------"
 λ>
```

Comment: Thanks sooo Much ! : )